# Play sounds through Python 2.7 Ubuntu on Windows 10

Tags: python, ubuntu, windows-10

I'm using Python 2.7 for Ubuntu on Windows 10 which generally has been smooth enough to use following Linux instructions. However I keep getting tripped up trying to play sound and no matter what modules I've tried I seem to get similar issues

I have tried the following modules/calls:

```py
import utilFunctions
utiFunctions.wavplay(path/to/file)
```

```py
from playsound import playsound

playsound('./test.wav')
```

etc, I've tried all the examples [here](https://pythonbasics.org/python-play-sound/) to no avail

Regardless of which method I use I get the same error:

```py
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
```

I assume it's a driver issue or convincing the system that even though it's bash I want to route it to windows to then handle playing out of my speakers there.

I was pointed to looking at aplay but it's much further out of my depth of knowledge and hence looking here. Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT: per the comments I believe it is a sound card recognition issue after all, though I am having trouble getting that to be noticed. I tried the following:

```
> aplay -l
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...
```

```
> sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.4.0-17134-Microsoft/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module snd-hda-intel not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-17134-Microsoft
```

I know I'm not supposed to be modifying lib/modules and there wasn't anything there so I think I'm missing a key piece to go forward. Any ideas?

Comment: card 0 apparently needs to be mapped to a Windows audio device in ubuntu, I'm guessing you need to do that in ubuntu configuration / settings not in your python code.  The ubuntu, SuperUser, or unix stack exchange sites might be able to tell you how.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be the sound card configuration, not Python 2.7.
Actually, Playsound 1.2.2 works in Python 2.7.
See here ...
https://pypi.org/project/playsound/

Have you tried adding your user to the sound group?

You can find a solution for ALSA lib errors here ...
https://askubuntu.com/questions/342420/cannot-play-sound-alsa-lib-errors